# Enabling Excerpts with Wintersmith

Tags: node.js, pug, wintersmith

I can't get Wintersmith to generate excerpts on the `index` page.

I see this:

```
if article.intro.length > 0
      != typogr(article.intro).typogrify()
    if article.hasMore
      p.more
        a(href=article.url) more
```

But I'm not sure what to adjust for the length. I tried 1, 100, -1 and nothing seems to trigger the `more`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `article.intro` property contains all the html up to the first `<h2>` or `<hr>` tag (configurable). So to control the length of your excerpts you just add the tag where you want the divider between intro and full article to be. If no divider is found intro will contain the entire article and the `hasMore` will be false.

For example

```
---
title: My Article
---

This would be the intro of the article

## This headline separates intro and full article

And this would be the body
```

Here's how it's implemented:
https://github.com/jnordberg/wintersmith/blob/master/src/plugins/page.coffee#L113